# "at" function is not working from schedular from lumen

Tags: php, laravel, cron, scheduled-tasks, lumen

Currently i am using PHP 5.6.32 and Laravel Framework Lumen (5.4.6) (Laravel Components 5.4.*).

My problem is, when i use

```
$schedule->call('App\Http\Controllers\SebiController@frickSchedule',["id"=>3])->everyMinute();
```

It is working fine.

But when I use:

```
    $schedule->call('App\Http\Controllers\SebiController@frickSchedule',["id"=>3])->at("14:32");
```

the `at` function it is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation (https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/scheduling)

'at' cannot be called inmediately. Because now Laravel doesn't know when to schedule exactly. (14:32 on Mondays?, Tuesdays? Fridays?)

So if you want it to be executed daily at 14:32 use 
`->dailyAt('14:32')`

Otherwise you need to specify the interval more precise like
`->weekly()->mondays()->at('14:32');`

In the example above 'at' can be used!